# Using Linq to XML to parse XML file with separate metadata element

Tags: c#, xml, linq, metadata

I have an xml file with the following format that I'm trying to parse with C# Linq to XML. The problem is that it has this separate metadata element which is the only thing identifying the values below. Is there a good way to do this? I don't have any power to change the format of this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8?>
  <dataset xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <metadata>
      <item name="Address Line 1" type="xs:string" length="512"/>
      <item name="Address Line 2" type="xs:string" length="512"/>
      <item name="Date Of Birth" type="xs:dateTime"/>
    </metadata>
    <data>
       <row>
         <value>123 Main St</value>
         <value xs:nil="true" />
         <value>1970-01-01T00:00:00</value>
       </row>
       <row>
         <value>125 Main St</value>
         <value>Apt 1</value>
         <value>1980-01-01T00:00:00</value>
       </row>
    </data>
</dataset>
```

The actual file has about 30 item and corresponding value elements in each row and several hundred row elements following this format. I'm basically looking for the best way to match up the metadata to the values. If Linq to XML is not the best way to achieve this, I'm open to other suggestions that work with C# and .NET 4.5.

I tried just collecting the metadata items in a list and using indices to match them to the values, but it seems to build the list in an arbitrary order, so I'm not sure I can rely on that ordering to identify the values.

```
  XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"Export.xml");
  XNamespace xns = "http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/";
  var metadataQuery = from t in xdoc.Descendants(xns + "item") select t;
  List<XElement> metadata = metadataQuery.ToList(); // This list appears to be ordered randomly
```

Comment: Please [edit] post and clarify following: What is wrong with the way you currently do that? In what way you want to improve/change your existing code? What is you "better" criteria for the task?

Answer (score 0):

The order of elements is always the same, in the order in which they appear in the xml file.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"Export.xml");
XNamespace xns = "http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/";

var metadata = xdoc.Descendants(xns + "item").ToList();
var data = xdoc.Descendants(xns + "row").ToList();

foreach (var datum in data)
{
    var values = datum.Elements(xns + "value").ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(metadata[i].Attribute("name").Value + ": " + values[i].Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method to parse file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement dataset = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace ns = dataset.Name.Namespace;
            var results = doc.Descendants(ns + "row").Select(x => new {
                firstAddr = (string)x.Elements(ns + "value").FirstOrDefault(),
                secondAddr = (string)x.Elements(ns + "value").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault(),
                dob = (DateTime)x.Elements(ns + "value").Skip(2).FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```